# Just started java "reached end of file while parsing" error

Tags: java, parsing-error

I literally just started java this week. I am enjoying myself so far, but I've run in to an error. I just need help with what I did wrong. I did exactly what it said in the description the site I'm learning java off of said to do. I'm stumped. I tried looking it up but a lot of the stuff I looked up makes sense to me. Please help. I'm embarrassed that I can't get this right.

```
package conditionallogic;


public class IFStatments {

 public static void main(String[] args) {

  int user = 21;

  if (user <= 18) {
   System.out.println("User is 18 or younger");
  } else if (user > 18 && user < 40) {
   System.out.println("User is between 19 and 39");
  } else {
   System.out.println("User is older than 40");
  }
 }
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jbeTh.jpg

Comment: Please post relevant code here . Not the images.

Comment: Don't get discouraged Medusa. Programming doesn't come easy for most people, and it will get frustrating. But once you figure something out, that feeling makes it worth it. Stick in there.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot one closing `}`.

Every opening `{` needs one closing `}`

Comment: Thank you so much! I must have overlooked it. I'm sure little things like that will become more apparent in the future. I'm looking forward to doing more coding! I'm just doing simple stuff right now, but I hope to make games in the future.

Comment: Why is this downvoted? It seems like the correct answer to me.

Comment: All the best Medusa. Keep going. Just ignore the down voting people here and don't be discouraged. @Austin, I have the same point. This is what I have been trying to bring to stackoverflow moderators notice. downvoting has become a fashion for few people around here.